# Once div is closed/add class

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to add a class 'hidden' to a div once the user has clicked to close it. My code below sets a cookie for 7 days so I want that class to be active for that time. Is this poss? Hoping it's an easy fix

My JS:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    // if the cookie exist, hide the element
    var hide = Cookies.getJSON('hide');

    if (hide && hide.element)
       $(hide.element).hide();

    $('#hideshow').on('click', function(event) { 
         $('.following_prompt').addClass('hidden');      
         $('.following_prompt').hide();

         Cookies.set('hide', {element: '.following_prompt'}, { expires: 7 });
         return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: css class is a part of the DOM , not cookie. You may set that class on the control everytime you check for the cookie value. Alternately, you can append the cookie to have a property for css class.

Comment: Awesome .... errrr how do I do this?? I ripped this bit of JS from somewhere else on SO lol

Comment: var cookieObj = { element: '.following_prompt', className: 'hidden' }; $.cookie("hide", $.param(cookieObj), { expires: 7 });

Comment: mmmm this isn't working! 

`jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    // if the cookie exist, hide the element
    var hide = Cookies.getJSON('hide');

    if (hide && hide.element)
       $(hide.element).hide();

    $('#hideshow').on('click', function(event) { 
         $('.following_prompt').hide()

         var cookieObj = { element: '.following_prompt', className: 'hidden' }; $.cookie("hide", $.param(cookieObj), { expires: 7 });
    });
});`

Comment: Check this : https://jsfiddle.net/5g67btrL/1/

Comment: weird - that example does nothing.

Comment: That was just an example. you need to run that code locally to see the creating and extraction of cookie values.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to use a class. You could use .is(':visible') but I created the example so that you can see what the code would look like to add/remove a class.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){

  $('#hideshow').on('click', function(event) {
        var $following_prompt = $('.following_prompt');
      if($following_prompt.is(":visible"))
          $following_prompt.addClass('hidden').hide();      
      else
         $following_prompt.removeClass('hidden').show();
         event.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/5g67btrL/

Comment: This removes setting the cookie?

Comment: yes. why would you need a cookie just to see if a div is hidden or not. It's a waste.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a helper class like: [Small Cookies JavaScript Helper](https://github.com/tdd/cookies-js-helper).

1. Download js file in https://raw.githubusercontent.com/tdd/cookies-js-helper/master/src/cookies.js to local.
2. Include path in your HTML file to load ***Small Cookies JavaScript Helper***.

**Example of use:**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    // if the cookie exist, hide the element
    var hide = Cookie.get('hide');

    if (hide !== '')
       $(hide).hide();

    $('#hideshow').on('click', function(event) { 
         $('.following_prompt').addClass('hidden');      
         $('.following_prompt').hide();

         Cookie.set('hide', '.following_prompt', { maxAge: 7*(3600*24) });
         return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: Nope - this doesn't work. This isn't adding a class name of hidden to .following_prompt